# ¿Cómo puedo preservar los archivos de configuración que me genera volumenes de docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, smtp

Hola mis estimados expertos, ¿Alguien me podria ayudar con la siguiente cuestión?

Tengo mi propio servidor de correo fucionando, ahora el detalle es que renté un nuevo VPS e instale docker, ahora lo quiero es migrar mi servidor de correo a docker para colocarlo en mi VPS de docker.

La razón de esto es:

- Tener todo pre-configurado en docker y en caso de fallo puedo levantar mi servidor de correo rápidamente- -el vps donde tenía el correo realmente se desperdiciaba ya que no tengo mucho tráfico en él.

Lo dividí en 3 contenedores de docker: estoy usando `docker compose` en la version 3.3

```
Mysql
Dovecot
Postfix
```

Ahora mi problema es que quiero que `/etc/postfix` sea un volumen para poder editar la configuración rápidamente.

Entonces probé usar un volumen de host:

```
volumes: - "./postfix:/etc/postfix"
```

Pero pasa que en dicho volumen aparece vacío y los archivos de configuración de `postfix` no son escritos o son eliminados, motivo por el cual `postfix` no inicia y mi contenedor muere.

Entonces lo que se me ocurrio fue crear un volumen nombrado y aqui si se crean sin problema los archivos de configuracion de postfix y todo funciona bien, entonces copie esos archivos y los meti a mi volumen de host `"./postfix:/etc/postfix"`, pero pues tampoco me inicia mi `postfix`.

Alguna ayuda, ¿cómo puedo preservar los archivos de configuración que me genera postfix? ya busque en internet y en la documentación de docker y `docker-compose` pero nada me ayuda.

y necesito usar volumen de host y no volumenes nombrados por que mi idea es poder reutilizar esos contenedores.

Alguna ayuda plisssss ya no sé qué hacer

Answer (score 0):

Cuando mapeas un volumen desde el archivo de docker-compose, lo que pasa realmente es que estas sobreescribiendo la carpeta que esta dentro del contenedor con la carpeta que esta fuera, por eso es que la carpeta en **/etc/postfix** esta vacia.

Debes iniciar el contenedor sin hacer el mapeo, luego copias la carpeta **/etc/postfix** desde dentro del contenedor para tu server, detienes el container y luego lo inicias con el mapeo.

Para copiar el **/etc/postfix** desde el contenedor, debes conocer el id o el nombre del tu contenedor, supongamos que tu contenedor se llama **postfix_container** y que estas dentro de la carpeta donde quieres copiar los archivos  entonces debes usar(no olvides el punto al final):

```
docker cp postfix_container:/etc/postfix .
```

Ahora ya puedes hacer el mapeo en el docker-compose y todo ira bien.